# Getting email from PHP script when page is not being accessed

Tags: php, email

I have a 404 page on my website with a short PHP script that emails me if that page was accessed (if a 404 error occurs) and if `HTTP_REFERER` is set, that way I can know what page caused the error and fix it.

Here is the script:

(The returnPage and destination variables are used to link the user back i.e. :

`<a href="<?php echo $returnPage ?>">Click here to return to the <?php echo $destination; ?>.</a></p>`

).

```
$returnPage;
$destination;
$err404;

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    $returnPage = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $destination = "previous page";
    $err404 = "this page: $returnPage";

    $message = "A 404 error occurred from $err404";
    mail('myemail@mail.com', '404 error', $message);
} else {
    $returnPage = './index';
    $destination = "home page";
}
```

So, a sample email, if there was a broken link on my index page, would look like:

> > A 404 error occurred from this page: http://example.com/index.php

This script was working perfectly for a few weeks until this afternoon when suddenly I started getting emails saying a 404 error occurred from every page I accessed. (I added some new JavaScript (unrelated to the 404 page) and was making sure I ftp'd all the files to my server properly. When this happened)

I use iPage as my host. I have a feeling it has something to do with the host but I'm not sure. Does anyone know why this is happening?

**Edit:**

The PHP is embedded into the HTML of the 404 page *only*

Comment: How is this code called?

Comment: Imbedded into the HTML @JohnConde

Comment: Of what HTML? Each page?

Comment: No haha just in the 404 page...that way if that page is accessed I get the email

Comment: Not enough information there seems to be no bugs in that script

Comment: I know that's what I don't understand there is no reason why it should be happening